# Flutter, Fluro "anonymous closure"

Tags: flutter, dart

I just started learning Dart/Flutter, and I have been advised to use the Fluro package for navigation.

Is it possible to switch between 2 StatefulWidget "pages" with Fluro router?
I had no problems when switching between stateless widgets, but when I've tried to make them stateful, I got this error: "The return type 'Page2' isn't a 'Widget', as defined by anonymous closure." I can't figure out what I should change in the code.

```
class FluroRouter {
  static Router router = Router();
  static void setupRouter() {
    router.define("Page2", handler: page2Handler);
    router.define("Page1", handler: page1Handler);
  }

  static Handler page2Handler = Handler(
      handlerFunc: (BuildContext context, Map<String, dynamic> params) => Page2());

  static Handler page1Handler = Handler(
      handlerFunc: (BuildContext context, Map<String, dynamic> params) => Page1());
}


class BasePage2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() {
    return Page2();
  }
}
class Page2 extends State<BasePage2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome',
      home: Scaffold(
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
            child: Icon(Icons.router),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'Page1');
            },
          ),
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Page 2"),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Text("Page 2"),
          )),
    );
  }
}

//Page 1 looks the same, only the text says "Page 1"
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question in text, not just a screenshot of your IDE. (Specifically `Page2` given the error message)

Comment: @Khalos Thank you for your advice! Is it ok like this?

Comment: Yep, looks good. Including code like this will likely get you more/better answers. It also makes it more searchable if others have similar issues. Welcome to StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the `StatefulWidget` and not the `State`:

```dart
... => BasePage2()

... => BasePage1()
```

Comment: Thank you very very very much! It finally works. :)